# cudaMemcpy returns success but does not copy anything

Tags: cuda

below are the things I have checked with cuda-gdb:

1. the contents of src are correct
2. cudaMalloc, malloc, and file I/O are successful
3. cudaMemcpy returns cudaSuccess
4. the problematic cudaMemcpy is called and throws no errors or exceptions
5. destination is allocated (cudaMalloc) successfully

Below are relevent parts of the code: `wavenet_server.cc` mallocs the source, copies data from a file to the source, and calls `make_wavenet`. `wavenet_infer.cu` calls constructor of `MyWaveNet` and calls `setEmbeddings`.

wavenet_server.cc:

```
#include "wavenet_infer.h"
void readArrayFromBinary(void* array, size_t len, size_t num_bytes_per_elem, const char* file_name) {
  FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  fread(array, num_bytes_per_elem, len, file);
  fclose(file);
}

void setEmbeddingCurr(const char* fileName,  size_t len) {
      this->embedding_curr = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * len);
      readArrayFromBinary((void*)this->embedding_curr, len, sizeof(float), fileName);
    }

void setWavenet(void) {
      this->wavenet = make_wavenet(this->num_samples,
                                  this->batch_size,
                                  this->embedding_prev,
                                  this->embedding_curr,
                                  this->num_layers,
                                  this->max_dilation,
                                  this->dilate_weights_prev,
                                  this->dilate_weights_curr,
                                  this->dilate_biases,
                                  this->res_weights,
                                  this->res_biases,
                                  this->skip_weights,
                                  this->skip_biases,
                                  this->conv_out,
                                  this->conv_end,
                                  this->is_using_embed_tanh,
                                  this->implementation);
    }
```

wavenet_infer.cu:

```
#include "nv_wavenet.cuh"
typedef nvWavenetInfer<float,float, R, S, A> MyWaveNet;
    void* make_wavenet(int sample_count,
                                       int batch_size,
                                       float* embedding_prev,
                                       float* embedding_curr,
                                       int num_layers,
                                       int max_dilation,
                                       float** in_layer_weights_prev,
                                       float** in_layer_weights_curr,
                                       float** in_layer_biases,
                                       float** res_layer_weights,
                                       float** res_layer_biases,
                                       float** skip_layer_weights,
                                       float** skip_layer_biases,
                                       float* conv_out_weight,
                                       float* conv_end_weight,
                                       bool use_embed_tanh,
                                       int implementation
                                       ) {
    MyWaveNet* wavenet = new MyWaveNet(num_layers, max_dilation, batch_size, sample_count,
                                                                       implementation, use_embed_tanh);

    wavenet->setEmbeddings(embedding_prev, embedding_curr);

    // We didn't use biases on our outputs
    std::vector<float> dummy_bias_first(S, 0);
    std::vector<float> dummy_bias_second(A, 0);

    wavenet->setOutWeights(conv_out_weight,
                           dummy_bias_first.data(),
                           conv_end_weight,
                           dummy_bias_second.data());

    for (int l = 0; l < num_layers; l++) {
        wavenet->setLayerWeights(l, in_layer_weights_prev[l],
                                    in_layer_weights_curr[l],
                                    in_layer_biases[l],
                                    res_layer_weights[l],
                                    res_layer_biases[l],
                                    skip_layer_weights[l],
                                    skip_layer_biases[l]);
    }

    return (void*)wavenet;
}
```

nv_wavenet.cuh:

```
nvWavenetInfer (int numLayers, int maxDilation, int batchSize, int numSamples, int impl=0, bool tanhEmbed=true) : m_numLayers(numLayers), m_maxBatch(batchSize), m_maxSamples(numSamples), m_implementation((nvWavenetInfer::Implementation)impl), m_tanhEmbed(tanhEmbed) {


            m_maxDilation = maxDilation;

            /*
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_yOut, numSamples*batchSize*sizeof(int))); // one-hot vector represented as single value indicating which value is set
            gpuErrChk(cudaMemset(m_yOut, 0, numSamples*batchSize*sizeof(int)));
            */
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_outputSelectors, numSamples*batchSize*sizeof(float)));

            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_embedPrev, A*R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_embedCur, A*R*sizeof(T_data)));

            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_Wprev, numLayers*2*R*R*sizeof(T_weight)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_Wcur, numLayers*2*R*R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_Bh, numLayers*2*R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_Lh, numSamples*numLayers*batchSize*2*R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_Wres, numLayers*R*R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_Bres, numLayers*R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_Wskip, numLayers*S*R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_Bskip, numLayers*S*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_XtOut, numLayers*R*batchSize*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_skipOut, numLayers*S*batchSize*sizeof(T_data)));

            // For now, just burn memory as though all layers had the maximum dilation value
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_XtIn, (m_maxDilation+1)*(numLayers+1)*R*batchSize*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_hOut, numLayers*batchSize*R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_aPrev, numLayers*batchSize*2*R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_skipIn, numLayers*S*batchSize*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_skipOutFinalAccumulate, A*batchSize*S/R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_outAccumulate, A*batchSize*A/R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_yInPrev, batchSize*sizeof(int))); // one-hot vector represented as single value indicating which value is set
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_yInCur, batchSize*sizeof(int))); // one-hot vector represented as single value indicating which value is set

            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_WskipOut, A*S*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_BskipOut, A*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_Wout, A*A*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_Bout, A*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_skipOutFinal, A*batchSize*S/R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_out, A*batchSize*A/R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_p, A*batchSize*sizeof(T_data)));

            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_h, numLayers*batchSize*R*sizeof(T_data)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_hSample, numLayers*batchSize*sizeof(int)));
            gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_ySample, batchSize*sizeof(int)));

            if (impl == PERSISTENT) {
                gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_skipOutFinalAccumulate, A*batchSize*S/R*sizeof(T_data)));
                gpuErrChk(cudaMalloc(&m_outAccumulate, A*batchSize*A/R*sizeof(T_data)));
            }

        }
virtual void setEmbeddings (float* embedPrev, float* embedCur) {
            setActivation(m_embedPrev, embedPrev, A*R);
            setActivation(m_embedCur, embedCur, A*R);
        }
void setActivation(float* dst, float* src, size_t size) {
            gpuErrChk(cudaMemcpy(dst, src, size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that cudaMemcpy was not the issue. when examining device global memroy using cuda-gdb, one cannot do: `x/10fw float_array`. It will give incorrect values. To view, try this: `p ((@global float*) float_array)[0]@10`

Comment: Isaac, please remember to come back and accept this in a few days

Comment: @talonmies hi talonmies, thanks for your helpful comment, as usual. I noticed your feedback on my questions. Since I am new to stack, I am not too clear on what I am missing. Could you please share your thoughts on how I could make them better ? Thanks again